# Multiple Model File Uploader Using DRF

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a models.py as the following and I'm trying to make multiple upload files in one request.

and the other fields in the model i put the values in the back-end so, what i need exactly how to to send array of data (files) in one request and handle the files and create record for every single files separate?

I also read a lot and see a lot of answers, but I felt the solution depends on the case maybe because I didn't got it will

please any one can help me ?

models.py

```
file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='docs/', null=True, blank=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='file_created_by', blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = File
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        user = kwargs['context']['request'].user
        super(FileSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['status'] = 'in_progress'
        self.context["file_name"] = self.context['request'].FILES.get("file_name")

        obj = File.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return obj
```

views.py

```
class FileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return File.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user, updated_by=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `file_name` model field's default serializer field to `serializers.ListField` and update the `create` method in serializer to loop over the list to create multiple objects.

**Example**:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_name = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.FileField(
            max_length=100000,  # length of the file name
            allow_empty_file=False,
            use_url=False
        ),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('created_by', 'file_name', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        files = validated_data.pop("file_name")
        obj = None

        # can also use `bulk_create`, if too many files
        for file in files:
            obj = File.objects.create(file_name=file, **validated_data)
        return obj
```

**NOTE**: The serializer will now not output any `file_name` keys, if you use it for list usecase. For that, you can add another field `fname` or something as a `serializers.SerializerMethodField` and return the value of the file name.

**Example**:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_test_field(self, obj):
        # since your field would be a file, so you can access `name` attribute
        return obj.test_field.name

    fields = ('test_field', ...rest of the fields...)
```